# How can I free mysql result straight fetched as an array and stored in a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I very like the syntax :

```
$result = $db_connect->query("SELECT * FROM table")->fetch_assoc();
```

instead of more verbose

```
$query = $db_connect->query("SELECT * FROM table");
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
$query->free();
```

My question is how do I free results from memory in case 1 ?

In other words : Do assigning a new value to the variable does automatically free the results ?

I've searched for that on stackExchange / Google with no success...and I found it's an interesting question.

Comment: Since you're using the object-oriented interface, stick with that. Mixing and matching with the procedural style is messy.

Comment: Alright, I edit it, Thanks for advice ))

Comment: Can't be done with chaining.

Comment: use unset($query);

Answer (score 1):

Method Chaining (your first example) works by executing each following function on the object returned by the previous function.  So you can do `$db_connect->query("SELECT * FROM table")->fetch_assoc();` because [`query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object and that object supports the [`fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) method.

`fetch_assoc()`, in turn, returns...

> ... an associative array of strings representing the fetched row
>   in the result set, where each key in the array represents the name of
>   one of the result set's columns or NULL if there are no more rows in
>   resultset.

Since this result is an array (or `NULL`) and not an object, no further methods can be added to the chain after it.